# Combining these two SQL Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

i'm having troubling combining these two SQL queries. I have this original query which selects data from two tables, the related columns being Tasks.CustomerID and Customers.CustomerID. It's basically Tasks.* + Customers.Name

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_SelectTasksandName]
AS
SELECT TASKS.CustomerID, TASKS.DateCreation, TASKS.DateFinish, TASKS.Description, TASKS.Fees, TASKS.Hours, TASKS.InvoiceNum, TASKS.PaymentMethod,
        TASKS.Status, TASKS.TaskID, CUSTOMERS.Name
FROM TASKS, CUSTOMERS
WHERE (TASKS.CustomerID LIKE CUSTOMERS.CustomerID)
```

This works, but I've now been asked to limit this query to a specified amount of rows. I found this code which worked well for my other, simpler queries, but I can't seem to use it correctly with this query. This Limit code is below. (i.e all rows > @low && rows <= @high)

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CustomerID) as row FROM CUSTOMERS
    ) a WHERE ((a.row > @low and a.row <= @high)
```

This is the closest i've gotten, but i'm stuck here.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TASKS.CustomerID) as row FROM 
        (SELECT TASKS.CustomerID, TASKS.DateCreation, TASKS.DateFinish, TASKS.Description, TASKS.Fees, TASKS.Hours, TASKS.InvoiceNum, TASKS.PaymentMethod,
                TASKS.Status, TASKS.TaskID, CUSTOMERS.Name
        FROM TASKS, CUSTOMERS
        WHERE (TASKS.CustomerID LIKE CUSTOMERS.CustomerID))

) a WHERE (a.row > @low and a.row <= @high)
```

With an error "expecting as id or quoted id" on the first bracket on the last line.

Sorry for the noob question, appreciate any help you guys can give.

Comment: *row* is set as a possible [TSQL reserved word in future MSSQL releases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql#future-keywords). Consider escaping with square brackets or different alias. And why you use `LIKE` without a wildcard? Use the explicit `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, my SQL is definitely sloppy! I'll need to work on that.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Damn, and I thought I was being organised with that one! Thanks for the heads up!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

The query you are looking for can be written as:

```
SELECT tc.*
FROM (SELECT t.CustomerID, t.DateCreation, t.DateFinish, t.Description, 
             t.Fees, t.Hours, t.InvoiceNum, t.PaymentMethod,
             t.Status, t.TaskID, c.Name,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.CustomerID) as seqnum
        FROM TASKS t JOIN
             CUSTOMERS c
             ON t.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
     ) tc
WHERE tc.seqnum > @low ANDtc.seqnum <= @high
```

Comment: It says not to comment thanks but Thank you! I really appreciate it. Definitely need to work on my SQL style. You're a legend!

Answer (score 0):

I would write the query as follows:

```
;With CTE
As
(
    SELECT
        TASKS.CustomerID, 
        TASKS.DateCreation, 
        TASKS.DateFinish, 
        TASKS.Description, 
        TASKS.Fees, 
        TASKS.Hours, 
        TASKS.InvoiceNum, 
        TASKS.PaymentMethod,
        TASKS.Status, 
        TASKS.TaskID, 
        CUSTOMERS.Name, 
        Row_Number() over (Partition By Tasks.CustomerID Order by Tasks.CustomerID) as RN
    FROM TASKS
        Inner Join CUSTOMERS
            on (TASKS.CustomerID = CUSTOMERS.CustomerID)
    )
select *   -- just being lazy here - in production code you ALWAYS use an explicit field list
from CTE
Where CTE.RN > @low and CTE.RN <= @high  -- or whatever logic you need
```

Comment: Thanks Brian! I appreciate the reply!